# issue when trying to move two div's onkeydown

Tags: javascript, html

The code seems right to me but when i try to move the div with `class` ai using the key 'A' and 'Q' it doesn't work , it work only with the div which have the `class` player when hitting up and down arrow :

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/st93dq8z/)**

**JavaScript** :

```
var playerPosition = 0,
    playerPosition2 = 0;

window.onkeydown = function(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;

    if(key == 40) { // up arrow
        playerPosition += 5;

    } if(key == 38) { // down arrow
        playerPosition -= 5;
    }

    if(key == 113) { // q buttton
        playerPosition2 += 5;

    } if(key == 97) {
        playerPosition2 -= 5; // a button
    }


    var players1 = document.getElementsByClassName('player');

    for(var i = 0; i < players1.length; i++) {
        if (playerPosition < 0) {
            playerPosition = 0;
        }
        else if (playerPosition > 330) {
            playerPosition = 330;
        }
        players1[i].style.top = playerPosition + "px";
    }


    var players2 = document.getElementsByClassName('ai');
    for(var i = 0; i < players2.length; i++) {
        if (playerPosition2 < 0) {
            playerPosition2 = 0;
        }
        else if (playerPosition > 330) {
            playerPosition2 = 330;
        }
        players2[i].style.top = playerPosition2 + "px";
    }

 }
```

Comment: UM, A and q are not those key codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure where you got those keyCode values

```
a = 65
q = 81
```

http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Comment: Beat me to it. I believe there is also a typo in the players2 second if. Should be playerPosition2 instead of playerPosition?

Comment: when i hit the a key the two div's goes instantaneously to the top

Comment: The positions are initiated at 0. Change them to match the CSS starting position and it should work.

Comment: try to make the 2 div's move in the same time , they will still in the same position